# How do I change the current split's width and height?

Tags: split

I am working on split (using ^w+v, ^w+s) buffers, but sometimes I would like to widen a current split or change its height. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 350, accepted):

There are several window commands that allow you to do this:

- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>+/-</kbd>: increase/decrease height (ex. `20<C-w>+`)
- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>>/<</kbd>: increase/decrease width (ex. `30<C-w><`)
- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd>: set height (ex. `50<C-w>_`)
- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd>: set width (ex. `50<C-w>|`)
- <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>: equalize width and height of all windows

See also: `:help CTRL-W`

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the 3rd and 4th options can take _no_ count to resize to the maximum height/width.

Comment: on windows, Cygwin, vim : when you `vimdiff -o bigfile1.bash bigfile2.bash` : `ctrl-w =` : opens a MiniBufExplorer 3rd window on top (and the 3 windows are now equal in size), and closing that one makes the first .bash file's window 2 timse bigger than the 2nd .bash file window. Same operation with 2 .vim files gives same results. :( Same with `vim -o`

Comment: Asking for shortcut for the first two options  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16786/vim-split-horizontal-resize-shortcut

Comment: @Michael: It doesn't work, I have to put a large constant like `200` before them to maximize the window.

Comment: @job_start I don't know what to tell you. I wrote [a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337396/143088) using it in 2016, and it's still in use today with no complaints. `execute "norm! \<c-W>_"`

Comment: [The documentation](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#window-resize) says _"Set current window height to N (default: highest possible)."_

Answer (score 83):

You can also use the `resize` commands:

- `:resize [+-]N` - resize a horizontal split, increasing or decreasing height by N characters.
- `:vertical resize [+-]N` - resize a vertical split, increasing or decreasing height by N characters.
- `:resize N` - resize a horizontal split, setting height to N characters.
- `:vertical resize N` - resize a vertical split, setting width to N characters.

These are equivalent to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> commands. See [`:help window-resize`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#window-resize).

Comment: Similar to: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Resize_splits_more_quickly

Comment: I am so happy I finally found the easiest way to do this is resize command. Control commands are a menace, I keep playing ping pong without resizing any frame with it.. thank you @muru

Answer (score 57):

This is one of the few reasons I like to use vim's mouse mode.

If you use the GUI version, or your terminal supports sending drag events (such as xterm or rxvt-unicode) you can click on the split line and drag to resize the window exactly where you want, without a lot of guess work using the ctrl-w plus,minus,less,greater combinations.

In terminal versions, you have to set mouse mode properly for this to work

```
:set mouse=n
```

(I use 'n', but 'a' also works)

and you have to set the tty mouse type

```
:set ttymouse=xterm2
```

A lot of people say that a lot of time is wasted using the mouse (mostly due to the time it takes to move your hand from the keyboard to the mouse and back), but I find that, in this case, the time saved by having immediate feedback while adjusting the window sizes and the quickness of re-resizing (keep moving the mouse instead of typing another key sequence) outweighs the delay of moving my hand.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, I found in Gnome-terminal `:set mouse=n` is enough, but to enable when inside tmux `:set ttymouse=xterm2` is needed.

Comment: Absolutely true, I love keyboard, but this kind of things are better with mouse.

Comment: Totally agree with *"but I find that, in this case, the time saved by having immediate feedback while adjusting window sized and the quickness of re-resizing (keep movving the mouse instead of typing another key sequence) outweighs the delay of moingmy hand."*.

Answer (score 9):

Seems no one mentioned `z{nr}<CR>`.

If you `:h ^w_`, then will see `z{nr}<CR>` just below it, which have same effect as <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>.

If you do not need <kbd>z=</kbd> for spell check, and added below to `.vimrc`,

```
" vertical resize, z0<CR> minimize, z= equalize, z99<CR> maximize.
nnoremap z= <C-w>=
```

Then for change window height:

- <kbd>z0<CR></kbd> to minimize height of current window
- <kbd>z99<CR></kbd> to maxmize height of current window
- <kbd>z=</kbd> to make them all equal

Comment: this use of `z` is a little unintuitive. I think we should stick to `C-W` mappings. It's nice to know what's out there though.

Answer (score 9):

### [Resize splits more quickly](https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Resize_splits_more_quickly)

You can use the `:resize` command or its shortcut `:res` to change the height of the window. To change the height to 60 rows, use:

```
:resize 60
```

You can also change the height in increments. To change the height by increments of 5, use:

```
:res +5
:res -5
```

You can use `:vertical resize` to change the width of the current window. To change the width to 80 columns, use:

```
:vertical resize 80
```

You can also change the width in increments. To change the width by increments of 5, use:

```
:vertical resize +5
:vertical resize -5
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to be `Resize splits more quickly`, unless these commands are bound to keybindings, which has been done out of the box

Comment: Don't entirely agree Enan's statement. I like this answer imho

Answer (score 3):

For some reason (likely a plugin) the standard `C-w >` (etc.) did not work in my `~/.vimrc`.

These `.vimrc` additions worked (`Ctrl-Shift-Left` ... where `Left | Right` = left and right arrow keys, respectively.

```
" noremap <silent> <C-S-Left> :vertical resize +5<CR>
" noremap <silent> <C-S-Right> :vertical resize -5<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Left> :vertical resize +1<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Right> :vertical resize -1<CR>
```

Comment: I just tried this and got an error message when trying C-S-Left: "E16: Invalid range".

Comment: @Magnus : just looked at my `~/.vimrc` : as above.  Tested on `:vs` in Vim 8.2 (Linux system): works.  Perhaps you have an error in your lines (or some other issue)? https://imgur.com/gallery/h7lGYhK