# How can I get my windows back into a grid formation?

Tags: vim-windows

If I have windows arranged into four quadrants, as from the following sequence of commands:

- `:tabnew`
- `:vsplit`
- `:split`
- `<C-W>l`
- `:split`

then entering a command like `<C-W>J` will cause these to no longer be square; in this case, it will force one window to float at the bottom.

How can I do the opposite—that is, force the windows back into a square formation?

I've read `:help window-moving` but didn't see anything useful.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what you're trying to achieve when you press <C-W>J, which moves "the current window to be at the very bottom, using the full width of the screen," This means the windows will no longer be in a grid formation, by definition. What are you trying to actually do with your windows?

Comment: @Rich I think OP is just exemplifying a situation after which he may want to reset the windows to grid formation.

Comment: @GonçaloRibeiro Correct.

Comment: Related: [How to change the current split's width and height?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/514/467), [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467)

Comment: Though not an answer, if you find yourself hunting for code examples to make your own solution, I recommend checking the fabulous [Microviche](https://github.com/q335r49/microviche) project.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to arrange open splits into a grid of splits. In this case, the easiest way to get back into a grid is to manually rectify the structure:

1. close the split floating at the top
2. return to the split taking up half the screen
3. re-split it with `:split <file>`

This will return you to a grid. The way to maneuver splits without affecting the window layout is to use [count] <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> , which exchanges the current window with the [count] window.

Comment: I know that I can do this, but there are a couple of downsides. (1) If the window is the only view of a given buffer, and the buffer is dirty, you'll have to `:wq` or `:q!`, neither of which is desirable. (2) This will reset any window-specific settings, like the cursor position. (3) This will break any in-progress diffs. Essentially, windows are first-class citizens; destroying them and creating new ones simply isn't sufficient.

Comment: @WChargin Some of that goes away if you set vim to allow hidden buffers. But yeah...

Comment: Instead of closing the window and splitting the buffer to the desired location, split a new window where you want it to go, exchange it with the window you want to move, then close the (moved) new window.

Answer (score 4):

You could save your favourite layout using the `winsaveview` command.  Here I am mapping it to `\sv` for convenience:

```
nnoremap <Leader>sv :let g:myLayout = winsaveview()<CR>
```

Be sure to run that before you break your layout!  ;-)

Now if you ever accidentally break your layout, you can restore it:

```
nnoremap <Leader>rv :call winrestview(g:myLayout)<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

The default keys to re-arrange windows only work within their local split group:

```
CTRL-W x   Exchange current window with next (in group)
CTRL-W r   Rotate windows down/right (in group)
```

Or they break the window out to the top group:

```
CTRL-W  H | J | K | L   Move window to left/top/bottom/right-most edge
```

These are inadequate when you want to move the buffer into one of the other split groups.

But on such occasions, **the [WindowSwap plugin](https://github.com/wesQ3/vim-windowswap) can help**.  It lets you to swap the buffers of any two arbitrary windows.

```
<leader> yw   "Yank window": Yank the current window

<leader> pw   "Paste window": Swap the current window with the yanked window
```