# How can I move windows from a vertical split to a horizontal split?

Tags: split, vim-windows

I have three vertically split windows. I want the leftmost window to remain as it is, but move the two other windows from a vertical to a horizontal split. How can I achieve this?

I want to get from

```
----------------
| b1 | b2 | b3 |
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
----------------
```

to

```
----------------
| b1   | b3    |
|      |-------|
|      | b2    |
----------------
```

I can't figure out how to do this with the <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> maps listed in `:h window-moving`. The only thing I could think of involves opening and closing windows, not moving them, and before I create a mapping or command for it I wanted to ask if there isn't a way to do it by window movement. Here's what I've got:

1. <kbd>:spl</kbd> - split middle window
2. <kbd>:b 3</kbd> - open the buffer from the rightmost window in the new split
3. <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> - move cursor to rightmost window
4. <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - close current (rightmost) window

Comment: Related question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/how-can-i-get-my-windows-back-into-a-grid-formation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to do what you want, but you can accomplish this only with window movements by doing (start from the rightmost window b3):

1 - <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> - You'll have:

```
----------------
| b3           |
|------|-------|
|b1    | b2    |
----------------
```

2 - Go to b1 with <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

3 - <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to move b1 to the left.

You should have the layout you want now. The only downside I see with this method is that size and position of b1 are changed temporarily during the movement.