# Quickly arrange split windows into a grid layout?

Tags: vim-windows, split

Does vim have a way of arranging split windows in a grid pattern?  (Preferably, without closing existing splits, and without using a plugin.)

Tmux has some predefined windowpane layouts. For example, `ctrl+b alt+1` will divide the window horizonally (i.e., it moves existing splits into a tall, skinny configuration).  And `ctrl+b alt+2` will divide the window vertically (it moves existing splits into a short, wide configuration).

The one I'm interested in is tmux's `ctrl+b alt+5`.  If you have an even number of splits, it will arrange the splits in a regular grid pattern.  (Except for 8 splits, for some reason.  But if there are 9 splits, `ctrl+b alt+5` produces a 3x3 grid.)

In vim, using various combinations of `ctrl+w H`, `ctrl+w J`, `ctrl+w K`, `ctrl+w L`, `ctrl+w r`, and `ctrl+w x`, I can reproduce the tmux preset layouts, *except* for tmux `ctrl+b alt+5`.  And I know that I can get the grid layout by closing and re-splitting a window; but I would like to avoid that.

So, to restate my question:  Does vim have a way of arranging split windows in a grid pattern?  (Preferably, without closing existing splits, and without using a plugin.)

This question from 2015 is basically the same as mine:  [How can I get my windows back into a grid formation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/how-can-i-get-my-windows-back-into-a-grid-formation/1884#1884) (I guess I'm wondering if the answer is still "not really").

I am using vim version 8.1, on WSL Ubuntu in Windows Terminal on Windows 10.  (I know vim 9 exists, and I will upgrade sooner or later.  If the grid layout functionaly exists in version 9, please let me know.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Once you have things arranged the way you like, you can use a session or view to get back to that layout quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the [vim-orpheus](https://github.com/vds2212/vim-orpheus) plugin to display in the grid all the unsaved buffer at a glance with the command:

```
:Qall
```

I have also added the `:Grid` command to show all the listed buffer at a glance:

[image]

If you are only interested by the code of the `Grid` command here is the code:

```
let s:height_factor = 3

function! s:getwindowsize(winnr)
  let ret = winwidth(a:winnr)
  let ret = ret * winheight(a:winnr) * s:height_factor
  return ret
endfunction

function! s:getlargestwindow()
  let ret = 0
  let largestsize = 0
  for winnr in range(1, winnr('$'))
    let currentsize = s:getwindowsize(winnr)
    if currentsize > largestsize
      let ret = winnr
      let largestsize = currentsize
    endif
  endfor
  return ret
endfunction

function! s:addonewindow()
  let winnr = s:getlargestwindow()
  execute winnr . 'wincmd w'
  if winheight(winnr) * s:height_factor > winwidth(winnr)
    wincmd s
  else
    wincmd v
  endif
  " wincmd =
endfunction

function! s:spreadbuffers(buffers)
  if len(a:buffers) == 0
    return
  endif
  if winnr('$') > 1
    execute 'b' . a:buffers[1]
    only
  endif
  for i in range(2, len(a:buffers))
    call s:addonewindow()
  endfor
  let winnr = 0
  for bufnr in a:buffers
    let winnr = winnr + 1
    execute winnr . 'wincmd w'
    execute 'b' . bufnr
  endfor
endfunction

function! s:getlistedbuffers()
  let buffers = range(1, bufnr('$'))
  let buffers = filter(buffers, 'bufexists(v:val)')
  let buffers = filter(buffers, 'getbufinfo(v:val)[0].listed')
  return buffers
endfunction

function! s:spreadlistedbuffers()
  let buffers = s:getlistedbuffers()
  call s:spreadbuffers(buffers)
  1wincmd w
endfunction

" Grid All Listed
command! Grid call s:spreadlistedbuffers()
```

Comment: Thanks; I will take a look this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code do it for the listed buffers. I could adapt it for the visible buffers if needed.