# vim split horizontal resize shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

I can resize horizontal split windows by `ctrl-w-shift-<` and `ctrl-w-shift->`. I would like to have a shortcut for that.

Close to the topic, recently I learned about the following maps:

```
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

So I tried:

```
nnoremap <C-\<> <C-w>\<
nnoremap <C-\>> <C-w>\>
```

But it seems not to be working.

While waiting for an answer I'm using [@john-mo](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/227/john-om) mouse approach from [How do I change the current split's width and height?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/514/how-do-i-change-the-current-splits-width-and-height)

Answer (score 2):

Your mappings have two problems:

One problem can be solved easily: you don't need to escape `<` and `>` in the right-hand part of the mappings, for example, these ones work properly:

```
nnoremap <C-a> <C-w>>
nnoremap <C-b> <C-w><
```

Your second problem, which can't really be solved is that you're trying to map <kbd>Ctrl + <</kbd>, which is not possible. So you should try to use another key combination. (I already wrote an answer about how to debug a mapping which could have been useful to you in this case: [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841))

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>, many terminals will support <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period), although it's not obvious at first how to do this:

```
execute "set <a-,>=\<esc>,"
execute "set <a-.>=\<esc>."
nnoremap <silent> <a-,> :<c-u>vert res -<c-r>=v:count?v:count1:5<cr><cr>
nnoremap <silent> <a-.> :<c-u>vert res +<c-r>=v:count?v:count1:5<cr><cr>
```

You can supply a count or use the default of 5.

With alt maps I recommend using

```
set ttimeout ttimeoutlen=10
```

otherwise there can be a delay when pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> as vim waits to see if a , or . is coming.