# What is the vim equialent of CTRL+B, CTRL+<arrow-key> in tmux?

Tags: split, tmux

In tmux you can resize a pane gradually using the key combination `CTRL+B CTRL+<arrow-key>` to resize a split between panes.  Can the same be done in vim between a split-buffer pane?

Comment: You just want to resize? `:help :resize` and all the stuff under it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [How do I change the current split's width and height?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/514/how-do-i-change-the-current-splits-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

`<ctrl>+w` (to enter "resize mode") followed by `<n>+`/`<n>-` will make the window larger by `<n>` lines. E.g. `<ctrl>+w` then `5+` makes the current window 5 lines taller.

I often use `<ctrl>+w` and then `_` (underscore) to make the current window the larges possible. When I'm done I use `<ctrl>+w` then `=` to make all of the windows the same size.

Hope that helps.